# What is "dlta" and "ridlist" parameters used in Requests library (Python)

Tags: python-requests, url-parameters, quickbase

Guys I am working on getting data as tables from QuickBase using Requests library (Python). I found somebody doing it using the URL of the report, but he added two parameters to the URL like that:
&dlta=xs%xx&ridlist=xxxx.

Can anybody please tell me what are those two parameters, I searched for them in the internet but found nothing related to them.

Answer (score 0):

I've been using Quickbase for over ten years and haven't seen documentation for either of these parameters.  I have noticed that `ridList` seems to be used by Quickbase's grid edit view of reports (I suspect it's an ID for a server-side cached list of record IDs to display especially when using the type-ahead search of a report before choosing to grid edit) and `dlta` is used in the "Download report as CSV" button.

That example you're following may have simply copy and pasted a link generated by Quickbase as a hack to get a CSV instead of XML response. I recommend following the [Quickbase HTTP API Reference](https://help.quickbase.com/api-guide/intro.html) instead.  If you don't want an XML response, Quickbase also has a [JSON RESTful API](https://developer.quickbase.com/) which may be easier to work with.

Comment: Thank you Nathan, you helped me solve it.
Those parameters are part of the url generated by the "Save as a spreadsheet" button on Quickbase report pages.
After I read your answer I went to QuickBase and realized that **ridlist** is itereated every time you download the report, I set it to 9999999999999 on my report and it worked